# In petite-vue, how to respond to changes in a reactive object purely in JavaScript?

Tags: petite-vue

**In petite-vue, i need to respond to changes in a reactive object - and do it purely in JavaScript.**

I want to attach a watcher callback function directly in JavaScript. Because the value in question is modified in more than 1 user interaction, and also automatically, it's not a good option to put *v-on* or *v-effect* directives everywhere in HTML, where it can be changed. I want to have it done nicely, 1 feature in 1 place, not scattered.

Is there a way to do this simply in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

So far I found this way to list all the "dependecies" of a response to a state change neatly in one place, so one can have a full overview:

```
<main
  id="app"
  v-scope
  v-effect="stateVariable1, stateVariable2, saveStateToDB()"
  @vue:mounted="loadStateFromDB()"
>
```

Comment: this is a very good hack! thank you